# How to show Success and Failure Message in JEST test cases for the callback API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, jest-fetch-mock

How to write JEST test cases for the callback API success and failure.
Below is my code

```
function userLogin(username, password) {
  const reqBody = { companyEmailAddress: username, password, };
  const url = `${config.apiBaseUrl}${serviceMethodConstants.login}`; 

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(serviceFactory.postData(
      url,
      false,
      reqBody,
      function (response, dispatch) { 
        if (response !== undefined) {
          console.log(response )
        }
      }
    ));
  };
}
```

For same I wrote JEST test case, but it is not showing any error or success message as expected.

```
it("Login User Success on API call ", async () => {      
        const dispatch = jest.fn();
        const postDataResult = {
            200: 'success',
            400: 'error'
        };
        let url = "https://api/users/authenticate";
        let reqBody = {
          companyEmailAddress: "abcd@hotmail.com",
          password: "pass"
        };
        jest.spyOn(serviceFactory, "postData").mockReturnValue(postDataResult);
        userActions.userLogin("abcd@hotmail.com", "pass")(dispatch);
        expect(serviceFactory.postData).toBeCalledWith(
          url,
          false,
          reqBody,
          expect.any(Function)
        );  

        expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith(postDataResult);
});
```

Comment: My problem here is i am not able to show the success and failure message for the web services call

Comment: Can any body help me in this regards

Comment: the code you provided does not seem to be correct... You have `function login() {}`, also is this code executed inside a jest's `test` or `it` function?

Comment: I have written the code inside the jest test method.